# Merge List of Custom Objects to a Single List Object using Streams Java 8

Tags: java, java-8

I have ProductInfo object which looks like this

ProductInfo.java

```
    public class ProductInfo
    {
    private List<String> servicetagInfo;
    }
```

I have Order object like this which has list of Products info

OrderDetail.java

```
    public class OrderDetail
    {
    private String orderNum;
    private List<ProductInfo> productInfo;
    }
```

And then I have a Response object which basically has List of Order objects

Response.java

```
    public class Response
    {
    private List<OrderDetail> orderInfo;
    }
```

I am getting response as expected.But right now in this format

```
    orderInfo:
    0: {orderNum: "162293591",...}
     productInfo:
     0: {servicetag_info: ["7LSMW33", "49SMW33"]}
     1: {servicetag_info: ["JF6XN33", "CQ5XN33"]}
     2: {servicetag_info: ["5VRR523", "13LR523"]}
```

Here I am trying to merge productInfo List to be like this

```
    productInfo:
    0: {servicetag_info: ["7LSMW33", "49SMW33","JF6XN33", "CQ5XN33","5VRR523", "13LR523"]}
```

Just add all strings into one main property.

Here is my code

```
    List<String> serviceTagList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (OrderDetail orderDetail : arInvoiceOrderResponseBody.getOrders()) {  //Here i am getting orders from external service
        if (orderDetail != null) {
            if (orderDetail.getProductInfo() != null && orderDetail.getProductInfo().size() > 0) {
                for (ProductInfo productInfoDetail : orderDetail.getProductInfo()) {
                    if (productInfoDetail != null) {
                        if (productInfoDetail.getServicetagInfo() != null) {
                            for (String serviceTag : productInfoDetail.getServicetagInfo()) {
                                serviceTagList.add(serviceTag);
                            }
                       }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        ProductInfo productInfo = new ProductInfo();
        productInfo.setServicetagInfo(serviceTagList);
        orderDetail.setProductInfo(Arrays.asList(productInfo));
    }
```

Can anyone suggest how can i achieve same using streams in java so that it will be readable.

Comment: If you could ensure those **lists are not `null`** by their nature or from the methods returning their values, you could simplify things to         `List<String> serviceTagList = orderDetails.stream()
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .flatMap(od -> od.getProductInfo().stream())
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .flatMap(pi -> pi.getServicetagInfo().stream())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Set<String> tags = order.stream()
            .flatMap(order -> order.getProductInfo().stream())
            .map(ProductInfo::getServicetagInfo)
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Full implementation:

```
for (OrderDetail orderDetail : arInvoiceOrderResponseBody.getOrders()) {
    if (orderDetail != null && orderDetail.getProductInfo() != null) {
        orderDetail.getProductInfo().removeAll(null); // Remove any null elems
        Set<String> tags = orderDetail.getProductInfo().stream()
            .flatMap(product -> (product.getServicetagInfo() == null) ? null : product.getServicetagInfo().stream())
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
        tags.remove(null); // Remove null if exists
    }

    ProductInfo productInfo = new ProductInfo();
    productInfo.setServicetagInfo(tags);
    orderDetail.setProductInfo(Arrays.asList(productInfo));
}
```

Comment: After getting Set of strings i am trying to set it to List<ProductInfo> object which is a property of OrderDetail object as you can see at the bottom of my code.Basically inside product info i am getting more than one object.But i need to add all strings into one object with property servicetagInfo and set List<ProductInfo> object to OrderDetail

Comment: Updated solution.  FYI, this is not a platform for exact solutions.  If you want to understand streams, please look at tutorials, then come back for any further questions.

Comment: If this works for you, please mark it as correct, and upvote. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

With streams your code could be like this:

```
arInvoiceOrderResponseBody.getOrders().stream()
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .forEach(YourClassName::mergeProductInfo);
```

The method `mergeProductInfo` would be:

```
private static void mergeProductInfo(OrderDetail orderDetail) {

    List<String> serviceTagList = new ArrayList<>();

    if (orderDetail.getProductInfo() != null) {
        serviceTagList = orderDetail.getProductInfo().stream()
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .map(ProductInfo::getServicetagInfo)
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    ProductInfo productInfo = new ProductInfo();
    productInfo.setServicetagInfo(serviceTagList);
    orderDetail.setProductInfo(Arrays.asList(productInfo));
}
```

It could be simplified if you could be sure that you are not going to receive null lists or elements.